# Where is "Rue des Tourterelles" in Mauritius?

Tags: maps, gps-navigation, local-knowledge, mauritius

I am looking for `RUE DES TOURTERELLES, BAIE DU TOMBEAU, MAURITIUS`.

This street seems to exist, it was even the address of [this company](http://wap.companiesinmauritius.com/de/chin-hao-shipping-supplies-cc-ltd.Xb.mauritius-company-profile.html).

But impossible to find where in Baie du Tombeau it is exactly.

The street name is not findable on Google Maps nor Open Street Map.

Any idea where to find its location?
By extension, is there a database of all [Mauritius](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mauritius) streets?

Comment: Related: [Streets of Mauritius](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3403/1354) - yes I realise it's your question, but for future users I thought I'd link to it.

Comment: The company you mention is now defunct, you sure maybe a suburb or street hasn't been rebuilt, perhaps wiping the address? It's not on geonames, openstreetmaps, google maps, I'd say it likely doesn't exist any more, if it did used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rue des Tourterelles starts at -20.12672, 57.49795 and ends at -20.12634, 57.50161.

It was recently added [on OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/-20.12672/57.49794).